# Is there a function in docx module that can get the position of its cells?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

Would it be possible to get the position of a specific cell in a table using .docx?
Not too sure if I'm approaching this the right way.

Referring to the images, I want to replace the wall loss (3rd column) from one doc with its given values to another doc with the same corresponding Row Number and Tube Number.

I was thinking of doing

```
# Lists after extracting the values from doc #1
Rows = [1, 1, 1, 4, 4] 
Tube = [1, 2, 3, 1, 6]
Wall_Loss = ['LOSS', 37.6, 36.6, 30.6, 37.9]

# Iterating over these lists to find its corresponding positions in doc #2
for i in range len(Rows):
 if (Rows[i] and Tube[i]) in # POSITION OF CELLS:
  document2.tables[0].cell(POSITION,2).text = Wall_Loss[i]
```

Would this be viable?

[image: Doc 1]

[image: Doc 2]

Comment: What third-party module are you using to read the docx file? Mention it in your question and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Apologies but what does third-party module mean? Like the libraries I imported? (kinda new to python)

Comment: Modules are loaded into Python by the process of `import`ing them and yes, sometimes they're called libraries. "Third-party" means it not part of the Python standard library.

Comment: There are many Python ["docx" modules](https://pypi.org/search/?q=docx), so you should specify exactly which one you are using.